# What does the adverb "yesterday" modifiy in a clause?

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

Not only *yesterday*, but other Time Adverbs as well. What do they "modify" in a clause?

Example:

> The athletes ran yesterday

Answer (score 2):

McCawley describes time adverbs as sentence modifiers, which can be converted to V' modifiers by his Raising rule.  His discussion begins on page 255 of [The Syntactic Phenomena of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA226&lpg=PA226&dq=mccawley%20phenomena%20time%20adverb&source=bl&ots=uOiA2NdyUg&sig=wHL56n7jX7pyZVIFEM8fXiE7iQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNyJeAx47NAhUM4SYKHQ2TDQoQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=mccawley%20phenomena%20time%20adverb&f=false).

Comment: I completely agree with McCawley's statement. To me, it makes way more sense for adverbs of time to modify the sentence than the verb.

Answer (score 1):

It modifies the verb **ran**.

Remember adverbs of time tell us when an action happens. They also tell us how long or how frequent an action happens.

Comment: You are right. "yesterday" is simply an adjunct of temporal location modifying "ran". But I would analyse "tomorrow" as a pronoun so the adjunct is realised by an NP with a deictic pronoun as head.

Comment: Hi @BillJ, Sorry not a linguistic student here. Can you enlighten me about what you mean by "so the adjunct is realised by an NP with a deictic pronoun as head"? I am really interested about this

Comment: The reference of the time, place, participants in certain kinds of expression is determined in relation to the utterance-act. This phenomenon is known as **deixis**, and the expressions concerned are called **deictic**. So if I say to you on Tuesday _"The athletes ran yesterday"_, then "yesterday" would be a deictic expression. You'd know it means Monday since that is the day that "yesterday" refers to **relative to the time of my utterance**. And "yesterday", though a single word, is head of the NP(noun phrase) "yesterday", so the adjunct "yesterday" is an 'NP with a deictic pronoun as head'.